# Okta wont start Error: EACCES: permission denied

Tags: reactjs, linux, visual-studio-code, okta, okta-signin-widget

I'm trying to use Okta to install their sign-in widget using the documentation from Okta Sign-In Widget and React, https://developer.okta.com/code/react/okta_react_sign-in_widget/#config.  I have all my files set up just like the docs suggested but when I go to npm to start the project I get 70 warnings from the terminal all basically saying the same thing below, with the common

**Failed to parse source map from '/root/okta/okta-signin-widget/...', Error: EACCES: permission denied**

[Errors from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVJOc.jpg)

How do I resolve these warnings?

Answer (score 0):

You may have used `sudo` while installing an NPM package.

As you are on Linux, it should be enough to just:

1. `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm`
2. `npm install`
3. `npm start`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm using ubuntu on WSL2 on windows 11.  All my other projects npm start fine, it's just when I'm trying to implement Okta I get these warnings and tried your suggestions but that did not work unfortunately